# Need help diagnosing "User unknown in virtual alias table"

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, smtp

I'm using virtual alias maps to relay mail and I keep having some of the entries bounce. Postfix seems to know where they are supposed to go and when I run postmap -q for virtual_alias_maps and virtual_alias_domains they both return the correct data.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Aug  4 16:48:03 server2 postfix/error[53118]: 0ACABDABAA: to=<foo@bar.com>, orig_to=<bar@foo.com>, relay=none, delay=17221, delays=17221/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=SOFTBOUNCE (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

When I run

```
postmap -q "bar.com" hash:/path/to/virtual-alias-domain
```

it returns "bar.com" and when i run

```
postmap -q "bar@foo.com" hash:/path/to/virtual-alias-map it returns "bar@foo.com"
```

Is there something else I should be looking at? Also, what should the maps permissions be?

Comment: Does that `foo@bar.com` user exist?

Comment: Yeah, the "foo@bar.com" user exists and I can send mail to them directly.

Comment: How did Postfix decide to forward `bar@foo.com` to `foo@bar.com` if the virtual map points to `bar@foo.com`?  (By the way, terrible examples; very confusing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be right on the money with the permissions question (although I have a vague recollection that you got some sort of error message at startup if the files weren't readable, I'm not in a position to test that at the moment).  I'm guessing you're running all your command-line testing as root (where it'll definitely succeed) and not as whatever Postfix itself is running as.  The maps files need to be readable by all the Postfix processes; this can be achieved by any of:

- Being owned by the user running Postfix, and `u:r`
- Being grouped to the user running postfix, and `g:r`
- Being owned by (eg) `root:root` and `o:r`

Naturally there has to be suitable `x` bits on leading directory paths.

If it's not permissions, nothing particular comes to mind; for me, Postfix virtual maps Just Work.

One thing I am curious about is why you're looking up `bar@foo.com` when Postfix is trying to deliver to `foo@bar.com`.

Comment: The maps are both owned by root and are readable by other. I also have no errors besides the bounces. Is there a straightforward way I can see why it the mail is bouncing. “User unknown in virtual alias table” is not quite verbose enough to provide any help.

Comment: What other information would you need to diagnose the problem?  You've already got everything that Postfix is using to look up the map.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. Everything that I've read says that it should be working and it still isn't. I've set up test accounts using the same tables and they work fine and I can't find a pattern of why some won't work. I was hoping there would be some magic parameter to say exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Set `tell_me_what_im_doing_wrong = true`; or just set `dwim = yarly`.

Comment: I wish that was real :-/. I've read pretty much every relevant document on postfix.org and everything seems to be in order. I was just hoping I made some obvious mistake...

Comment: @devnill If you haven't already, try increasing the verbosity of the logs. See [debugging Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#verbose) for details.

Comment: Thanks cyberx86. I pastebined the results here: http://pastebin.com/GdDi4GpH. I'm not quite sure what it's telling me...It looks like it can read the map alright?

Comment: Where did `destination@otherdomain.com` come from?  This is why obfuscating logs is such a bad idea.  You do it wrong and then they make no sense.

Comment: Sorry about that. destination@otherdomain is found in the virtual_alias_maps file and should be where the mail is going. I've posted an unobfuscated copy of the log here: http://pastebin.com/GJVBWAhd. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have the same value for both `relay_domains` and `virtual_alias_domains`; they're different things, and it *might* be the cause of your problems.  Also, you *are* rerunning `postmap` on your hash file, right?  On a stylistic note, I prefer to put both my virtual domains and aliases into one file; keeps things more localised.

Comment: I removed relay_domains and reran postmap just to make sure it was there. Postmap -q confirms that the line is present and readable as well but its still rejecting. I did notice one thing when verbose logging is enabled though. Line 53 in the file I pastebinned (http://pastebin.com/GJVBWAhd) has an error that looks like there is a ` instead of a '. I can't find what is causing it in any of my files though.